# How to remove all duplicate occurrences or get unique values in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas data-frame with multiple occurrence of particular values. I want to either remove all the values that are duplicates or replace with NaN and finally get the name of column that has any number of unique values. Pandas drop_duplicates function only removes the rows that has duplicate value but I want to remove the values/cells in data-frame. Is there a solution for this?

Based on the input dataframe below, all the values except the first row of column "02" have duplicate occurrence in the dataframe, so column "02" is what I want. If the question is not clear please do let me know. Thanks.

`DF: 
      02  03:10  03:02  03:02:09
0  6716  45355  45355     45355
1  4047   4047   7411      7411
2   945   2478   2478       945`

Expected output:
col_with_unique_val = "02"

or

```
Expected output DF: 
      02  03:10  03:02  03:02:09
  0  6716  NaN NaN NaN 
  1  NaN NaN NaN NaN 
  2  NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

or

```
Expected output DF: 
    02
0  6716
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way

```
df.mask(df.apply(pd.Series.duplicated,keep=False,axis=1))
       02  03:10  03:02  03:02:09
0  6716.0    NaN    NaN       NaN
1     NaN    NaN    NaN       NaN
2     NaN    NaN    NaN       NaN
```

---

```
df.mask(df.apply(pd.Series.duplicated,keep=False,axis=1)).stack().index.get_level_values(1)
Index(['02'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Thank you @Wen-Ben for providing a one line solution. I am new to Pandas, could you provide some info on what is happening in the background?

Comment: @GopinathS we apply the duplicate check for each row then all dup value being masked as true ,then we using mask which will mask all true by nan . After that we stack which will automatically remove all the value is nan

Answer (score 2):

`stack`, then check duplicated. `where` to make all non-uniques `NaN`

```
df1 = df.stack()
uniques = df1[~df1.duplicated(keep=False)].tolist()

df.where(df.isin(uniques))
#       02  03:10  03:02  03:02:09
#0  6716.0    NaN    NaN       NaN
#1     NaN    NaN    NaN       NaN
#2     NaN    NaN    NaN       NaN

df.isin(uniques).any().loc[lambda x: x].index
#Index(['02'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Thank you @ALollz. Is there a way to get the column name that has some value apart from NaN, "02" in this case.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate your help. @ALollz